# SQL Like filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like, varchar

Welcome!

I am currently working on some C# and I encountered a rather silly issue. I need to fill ListBox with some data from database obviously. Problem is varchar filtering. I need to filter codes and display only the right ones.

Example of codes are: `RRTT, RRTR, RT12, RQ00, R100, R200, R355, TY44, GG77 etc. Four digit codes.`

I managed to filter only R-codes with simple `select * from table1 where code_field like 'R%'` but I get both R000 and RQ10 and I need to get R ones followed by numbers only.

So from example:

```
RRTT, RRTR, RT12, RQ00, R100, R200, R355
```

Only:

```
R100, R200, R355
```

Any ideas what should I add to the `like 'R%'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can make use of wildcards.  Here is one approach:

```
where rcode like 'R___' and       -- make sure code has four characters
      rcode not like 'R%[^0-9]%'  -- and nothing after the first one is not a number
```

Or:

```
where rcode like 'R[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

In other databases, you would normally do this using regular expressions rather than extensions to `like`.

Answer (score 0):

here solution using like

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    VALUES ( 'R123'),
           ( 'R12T' ),
           ( 'RT12' )
    ) AS t(test)
    where test like 'R[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
like 'S[0-9%]'
```

Friend came up with the solution, thanks anyway

Comment: Depends on dbms. ANSI SQL doesn't allow the [0-9%] regexp part.

Comment: @jarlh: it does "allow" that - it just won't treat it as something like a regular expression ;)

Comment: @Dashovsky your example will not work with MSSQL, your friend gave you wrong solution